# Mapbox Studio feature Z-ordering

Tags: sorting, mapbox-gl-js, z-order, mapbox-studio

I would like to order "circle" features in a layer in Mapbox studio. The entire Style, including this layer and other layers, is added to a map using GL.JS, and symbology for the layers are set in studio.

I see the documentation for [circle-sort-key](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#layout-circle-circle-sort-key) for gl-js style specification, but don't see where to set it along side the other properties (raduis, color, opacity, etc) for the layer style in studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the documentation doesn't give a detailed example, I'm adding my final solution here.
Following @steve-bennett's suggestion, to sort the smallest circles on top:

```
map.setLayoutProperty('layername','circle-sort-key',["*", -1, ["get", "propertyname"]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it appears you can't set it within Studio.

However, you can set it using JS if you want:

`map.setLayoutProperty('mylayer', 'circle-sort-key', ...)`

Comment: What a shame that you can't set this within Mapbox Studio. I am worried that doing it on the client side will affect performance for my users. Thanks Steve

Comment: I can't see why that would be the case.